# How to convert an unpacked value from binary data file to usable value in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert data values from the file into an array. What I have so far is

```
import os, io, struct, array

file=open('filename','rb')

myarray=[0]*1000

for i in range(100):
    myarray[i]=struct.unpack('i', file.read(4))
```

what ends up filling the array is something like

```
((5,),(24,),(10,)....)
```

How do I convert it to be like

```
(5,24,10,...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `chain` function to flatten your `tuple` of `tuple`s

```
from itertools import chain

result = ((5,),(24,),(10,))
result = tuple(chain(*result))
# (5, 24, 10)
```

Your code should look like so:

```
for i in range(100):
    myarray[i]=struct.unpack('i', file.read(4))

result = list(chain(*myarray[:100])) # you may want to keep this as a list
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Moses. It's telling me that "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" when I try to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: what did you try? `list(chain(*myarray))` should work

Comment: This is what I added to the code: `result=myarray
result=chain(*result)` and when I do that it now says `TypeError: 'itertools.chain' object is not subscriptable` if I try `list(result[0:10])`

Comment: you did `myarray=[0]*1000` so you can't chain the rest of the 900 indices that do not contain `(x,)`. See update